# Pointer to Pointer to Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

My function `passwords` takes `char**` as input. I need the function to place a specific char at a location. My program crashes and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I've narrowed it down to the pointer:

```
// The function
int passwords(int num, int line, char** letters, char** ptrPassword, int length) {
    char* password = *ptrPassword;

    // Later in the code
    password[location] = letters[line][0];
}
```

Here is my call from main:

```
char** password;
password = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
location = length;

//call function
printf("Password at %d is %s \n", rank, passwords(rank, 0, letters, password, length));
```

I'm not very experience with pointers, could someone please assist?

Main:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int passwords(int num, int line, char** letters, char** ptrPassword, int length);
int lengthOfString(char* string);
void print(char** letters, int length);

int location;

int main(){
    int numCase;
    scanf("%d", &numCase);

    int i, length;
    for(i = 0; i < numCase; i++){
        scanf("%d", &length);
        int j;
        char** letters = malloc(length*sizeof(char*));

        for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
            letters[j] = calloc(26, sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s", letters[j]);
        }
        int rank;
        scanf("%d", &rank);

        //print(letters, j);


        char* password;
        password = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        location = length;

        //call recursion
        printf("Password at %d is %s \n", rank, passwords(rank, 0, letters, &password, length));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Entire Function:

```
//recursive function
int passwords(int num, int line, char** letters, char** ptrPassword, int length){
    char* password = *ptrPassword;
    printf("Recursion #%d \n", line);
    if(line == length-1){
        printf("Line is equal to length \n");
        if(num > lengthOfString(letters[line])){
            printf("IF \n");
            if(num % lengthOfString(letters[line]) == 0){
                password[location] = letters[line][lengthOfString(letters[line])];
            }
            else{
                password[location] = letters[line][num % lengthOfString(letters[line]) - 1];
            }
            printf("location: %d \n", location);
            location--;
            printf("Password is: %s \n", password);
        }
        else{
            printf("ELSE \n");
            if(num / lengthOfString(letters[line]) == 1){
                *password[location] = letters[line][0];
            }
            else{
                printf("Alocation: %d \n", location);
                password[location] = letters[line][num / lengthOfString(letters[line])];
            }
            printf("Blocation: %d \n", location);
            location--;
            printf("Password is: %s \n", password);
        }
        return lengthOfString(letters[line]);
    }
    else{
        printf("Line is not equal to length \n");
        int scalar = passwords(num, ++line, letters, ptrPassword, length);
        if (num > scalar){
            if(num % scalar == 0){
                password[location] = letters[line][lengthOfString(letters[line])];
            }
            else{
                password[location] = letters[line][num % scalar - 1];
            }
            location--;
        }
        else{
            if(num / scalar == 1){
                password[location] = letters[line][0];
            }
            else{
                password[location] = letters[line][num / lengthOfString(letters[line])];
            }
            location--;
        }
        return scalar * lengthOfString(letters[line]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire program? It's impossible to see what's wrong with just what you've posted here.

Comment: Did  you use any debugger like `gdb` ? Please post more of your code.

Comment: What is the input for which you are getting a crash ? Your program has a compilation error as well, perhaps you meant `password[location]` instead of `*password[location]`.

Comment: `password = malloc(length * sizeof(char));` -> `password = malloc(length * sizeof(char*));` in case this is supposed to be an array of strings(?). A good rule to follow generally, is to never use any language mechanism unless you understand how it works and why it is needed. Do you understand _why_ there is a need of pointer-to-pointers in your program?

Comment: Why is your code "here is my call from main" different than the code in your "main"? Plenty of bugs there. Which of the 2 buggy versions are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
printf("Password at %d is %s \n", rank, passwords(rank, 0, letters, &password, length));
```

to

```
printf("Password at %d is %d \n", rank, passwords(rank, 0, letters, &password, length));
```

Since your `passwords` function returns an integer, not a string (`char *`). The same is evident from the compiler warning as well.

Comment: He should also most definitely not pass a pointer to a pointer-to-pointer.